# angularjs if/else if/else (switch) condition

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, if-statement, switch-statement

Hi I have a question here 
the code and data i have is here

```
     <div class="table-row" ng-repeat="x in myData" >
     <div class="table-cell" >{{x.accountNumber}}</div>
     <div class="table-cell"><span class="table-cell-asset">        
     {{x.totalAsset/100|currency}} </span><br/> 
     <span class="table-cell-changes">{{x.changePercent}}%/      
     {{x.changeDollar}}</span></div>
     </div>
```

changePercent is a float number that can be positive or negative or 0
i want to add a similar if/else statement to have is change color of changePercent and changeDollar for positive negative or 0.
I know a controller will do the job. I wonder if i can do it with some directive inline code to finish the comparison and change the color by result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-class` and css rules for your coloring:

```
<span class="table-cell-changes" 
      ng-class="{'green': x.changePercent > 0, 
                 'yellow': x.changePercent == 0, 
                 'red': x.changePercent < 0}">
       {{x.changePercent}}%/{{x.changeDollar}}
</span>
```